# Wrap whatwg-fetch in try/catch

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I make a request to a Node server from the client using [`whatwg-fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) and I get a non 200 response, I'd like to be able to `catch` that error and return a custom response.

For example:

```
const makeRequest = (endpoint) => {
    try {
        return fetch(`/api${endpoint}`, requestConfig)
            .catch(e => console.warn(e))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(e => console.warn(e))
    } catch(e) {
        // Never logs...
        console.warn(e);
    }
}
```

When I get a 502 or 404, for example, I'm still get a console.error in the console...

[image]

In Chrome console when I click to view the source of the error:
[image]

I don't understand why, if `fetch()` caused the error, why wrapping it in a try/catch doesn't catch this error?

How can I `catch` the errors from `fetch()` for a non-200 response?

Comment: You cannot use `try/catch` block to handle exceptions thrown asynchronously. Read more about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977516/catching-errors-in-javascript-promises-with-a-first-level-try-catch

Comment: There's no error (in the meaning of "exception") in your console. It's just the default logging that a network request failed.

Comment: @Mirceac21that's what `catch()` blocks are for, to catch rejected promises throw asynchronously. The link you posted confirms this. I have several `catch()` blocks above but it still isn't working