# mystery request proc_name= &params=

Tags: http, react-native

Trying to debug a new React-native application -- pretty large and it has no backend so I am trying to stub something out.

The request format is pretty foreign to me. Does anyone recognize this format or know how to handle it?

```
proc_name=customer_ref&params={"fields" : ["customerId"],"conditions":[{"mailAddress":"dsadsa"},{"pinCode":"ZHNhZHNh"},{"mailReceiveFlag":"1"}],"order" : ["customerCode desc"],"limit" : "1","table_name" : "Customer"}
```

React-native request code looks like this:

```
try{
    let result = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X_contract_id': contact_id,
          'X_access_token': access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'charset':'UTF-8',
        },
        body: 'proc_name='+proc_name+'&params={'+params+'}'
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.result;
    })
    return result;
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

The application errors out with Unhandled Promise Rejection before even making it to the server I whipped up. Pretty new here; am I doing something wrong at the frontend layer?

Comment: The params look more like a JSON string. If the Content type was application/json, I will recommend JSON.stringify(params).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your fetch structure to be like this.

```
async functionName(){

try{
    let result = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X_contract_id': contact_id,
          'X_access_token': access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'charset':'UTF-8',
        },
        body: 'proc_name='+proc_name+'&params={'+params+'}'
    });
    let resultjson = await result.json();
    return resultjson.result;
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}

}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: Because the fetch is asynchronous so you cannot use try-catch statements to handle exceptions thrown asynchronously. Take a look here if you need another info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977516/catching-errors-in-javascript-promises-with-a-first-level-try-catch

Comment: I see the same error either way, whether it's caught in the overarching try statement, or attached to the promise through the catch handler

Comment: Btw, is this code being put inside async function or not? Eg: async testfunction(){...}

Comment: ahh yeah sorry left that out DX

Comment: Also try to change your code based on the docs, I just updated the answer