# discord.js Returning after catching a promise error?

Tags: discord.js

Trying to make this work:

```js
    try{
       message.author.send(helpEmbed)
    }
    catch(error) {
       message.channel.send("Your dms are closed, cannot send help message.")
       return;
    }
    message.react('✅')
```

But `catch(error)` doesn't work for a promise error (as the actual error log calls it `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`). And I can't use `.catch(() =>` etc because then I can't put a `return` inside of it, meaning it won't stop the `message.react`. And in a `try/catch` you can't leave the `catch()` empty.

Comment: Can't you move the `message.react()` into `try` and use the example you described without return?

Comment: Well yes that would also work, but the main issue with the try/catch case as I said, error isn't caught since it's a promise error.

Comment: This question's answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977516/catching-errors-in-javascript-promises-with-a-first-level-try-catch

Comment: @Sean That worked! Was a little weird to fiddle with but it works as intended. Thanks, couldn't find a thread like that on my own.