# Why a promise reject is not catched within a try catch block but produces an Uncaught error?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a promise rejection that escapes a try catch block. The rejection causes an Uncaught exception which is something I can not comprehend.

If I add a reject handler in the Promise.then or a Promise.catch, the rejection gets captured. But I was hopping try catch will work in this situation.

What is happening here?

```js
class HttpResponse {
    json() {
        return Promise.reject('parse error')
    }
}

function fetch() {
        return new HttpResponse();
}


const res = fetch();

try {
    res.json().then(json => {
        alert(`json: ${json}`);
    }
    //,reason => {
    //    alert(`promise.reject ${reason}`);
    //}
    )
    //.catch(reason => {
    //    alert(`promise.catch ${reason}`);
    //})
} catch (e) {
    alert(`catch{} from try catch: ${e}`);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching Errors in JavaScript Promises with a First Level try ... catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977516/catching-errors-in-javascript-promises-with-a-first-level-try-catch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical reasons behind:

> HostPromiseRejectionTracker is an implementation-defined abstract
> operation that allows host environments to track promise rejections.
>
> An implementation of HostPromiseRejectionTracker must complete
> normally in all cases. The default implementation of
> HostPromiseRejectionTracker is to unconditionally return an empty
> normal completion.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-host-promise-rejection-tracker

Basically javascript engines can freely implement this spec. In the case of browsers you don't get the Error captured inside the try/catch because the error is not emitted where you think it should be. But instead it's tracked with this special event that throws the error in the console.
Also on nodejs, this event causes the process to exit if you have node set to exit on unhandled exceptions.

On the other side, if you instead use async/await, the rejection is treated like an 'error' in practical terms. Meaning that the newer async/await feature behaves in a different fashion showing that it is not only syntactic sugar for Promises.

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-throwcompletion

In sum, if you use Promise.then you are forced to provide a reject argument or chain it with .catch to have the rejection captured or else it will reach the console and in case of nodejs to exit the process if configured to do so (I believe new nodejs does this by default).
But if you use the newer async/await syntax you not only have a concise code (which is secondary) but a better rejection handling because it can be properly nested in a try/catch and it will behave like an standard Error.

Answer (score 2):

The technical reason behind this behavior is that a JavaScript promise invokes one of two callback functions for success or failure.

A promise does not emit an `Error` that is required for the try to work. it is not an Error (or more technically accurate) an instance of Error. It emits an event. You are encouraged to emit a new Error() if you need it to emit one. As pointed out here: https:developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/…

It emits an event that you can set up a handler for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseRejectionEvent –

Finally, await throws an Error as described in the spec: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await-rejected

Comment: Thanks but that I need to use reject or Promise.catch is something I'm already aware (see the commented code). I'm looking for a technical explanation of why the Uncaught exception escapes the try catch

Comment: If an error is not emitted, why I'm seeing the Uncaught error message in the console? It is kind of counterintuitive

Comment: Please see my edits. That should clearly answer your question.

Comment: Wow. This is another case of javascript WTF. It seems browsers captures the PromiseRejectionEvent events and rethrows them as errors (they appear like that in the console and they end nodejs process too). But on the other side if you use async await, the unhandled promise rejection gets properly treated as an error on first place. I thought async/await was just syntatic sugar. Javascript is really broken... Thanks for your time

Comment: @DanielSan - I do believe this shows the nature of maturation rather than being broken. Additionally, the spec does not tell Google to make V8 do anything - Google decided to do their own thing (others followed). Just trying to be fair. and an upvote would be appreciated if you really valued my time.

Comment: sure thing. About the state of javascript maturity this issue shows me that I should use newer syntax and features whenever possible because it fixes old problems

Comment: yes! I agree. It is crazy how hard it is to get people to realize that. The insistence on the use of jQuery is a great example of that. All languages suffer the same consequences brought by maturation.

Answer (score 2):

Promises have their own mechanism of handling errors with the `catch()` method. A `try / catch` block can't control what's happening when chaining methods.

```js
function fetch() {
  return Promise.reject('parse error');
}

const res = fetch();
res.then(json => {
  console.log(`json: ${json}`);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(`catch{} from chained catch: ${e}`);
});
```

However, using `async / await` changes that. There you don't use the methods of a promise but handle errors with a `try / catch` block.

```js
function fetch() {
  return Promise.reject('parse error');
}

(async function() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`catch{} from try catch: ${e}`);
  }
})();
```

Comment: What is the technical difference that allows try catch in the context of async await usage to capture the error?

Comment: The former example already has a `try / catch` mechanism built in. It would be like having a nested try / catch. That would result in only the inner block to catch the error. The latter example *throws* the error inside of using it's own mechanism. So in async context `Promise.reject('parse error');` would be equivalent to `throw new Error('parse error')`.

Comment: I was looking for a deeper technical reason. This is pretty obvious. But thanks anyway