# How do catch a reject from a function which contains a promise but does not return it

Tags: javascript, exception, promise

I have a function `main` which contains a promise but does not return one. Something like this.

```js
function main() {
  var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("testing");
      reject();
    }, 2000);
  });

  return "success";
}

main();
```

When I run the code, it gives an Uncaught (in promise) DOMException and stops the javascript code. I can't modify the `main` function at all. How can I catch the rejection?

Comment: wrap main() execution in try/catch

Comment: @Nonik that won't help because promise is rejected _asynchronously_. Wrapping `main()` in `try-catch` will only catch errors thrown _synchronously_ inside the `main` function.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979785/18472980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching Errors in JavaScript Promises with a First Level try ... catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977516/catching-errors-in-javascript-promises-with-a-first-level-try-catch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the ["unhandledrejection" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event).

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent error message
    // handle...
    // e.promise is the Promise that was rejected
    // e.reason is the object passed to reject()
});
```

Comment: Is there any other way? Unfortunately, this event is not available in my environment.